# Check if StringBuilder is null

Tags: c#, .net

I'm try to check if a `StringBuilder` is null after I have tried to populate it from the cache:

```
StringBuilder videoSitemap;

if (AppSettings.CachingEnabled)
{
    videoSitemap = CacheHelper.Get<StringBuilder>("DynamicVideoSitemap");
}

if (videoSitemap == null)
{
    videoSitemap = new StringBuilder();
    ....
}
```

But I am getting the following error when trying to compile:

> CS0165 Use of unassigned variable 'videoSitemap'

How do I do this and then check if the object is null - if I instantiate it but don't use caching then the `StringBuilder` will never be null

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to assign default null to avoid this error.

```
StringBuilder videoSitemap = null;
```

Comment: hahaha, so simple.  Thanks! I'll accept in 12 mins (when it lets me)